# CRM dynamics 365 javascript - detect when user navigates away from page

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I need to capture telemetry information that captures details such as when the user opens a form, closes it or navigates away from the form.

To do this, I have javascript calls to a telemetry api. In the case below, when the user navigates away or closes the tab, I would like to trigger "mymethod" which will call the api method to capture this event.

I am trying to trigger a javascript method when the user navigates aways from the form. I have this script which is on the CRM form. The below code does not work.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {  
    console.log('onbeforeunload triggered...');
    mymethod();
    return true;
};
```

Ideally I would like to be able to detect when the user navigates away from the page, or closes the page. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does not work means? Totally not triggering? Working on back button, not working on save & close, etc??

Comment: The event does not trigger when i navigate away (e.g click on the browser back button) try to close the browser.

Comment: You need a new approach, this won't work, due to the complex structure of D365 forms. Also, I perceive XY: what should this handler do ? Are you trying to do something when autosaving ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish in your `mymethod()`?  Can it be attached to `onSave()` or `onChange()`?

Answer (score 2):

This will probably never work - that type of code within CRM is unsupported.

[Microsoft Dynamics 365 and the importance of staying supported](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/microsoft-dynamics-365-and-the-importance-of-staying-supported/).

> Microsoft provide a set of tools and guidelines describing the things
>   we can do, they also tell us the – unsupported – things we shouldn’t
>   do. It’s all on the MSDN. Un-supported scenarios that commonly occur:
>
> - All JavaScript interactions within the application pages must only be performed using functions defined in Xrm.Page & Xrm.Utility
>     namespaces, i.e. don’t directly interact with the page DOM.

I would suggest asking a new question which focuses on your [end goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have told us something that doesn't work (but we wouldnt really expect it to) - you havn't actually told us what you are trying to achieve.